# Find the V(t) across the capacitor in this 2nd order circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac

I'm new to this so firstly I apologize for doing the picture in Paint but I didn't know any other way to do it.

I found this exercise and I was having some trouble wrapping my head around it.
We have to find the voltage across the capacitor but the problem is that we have an AC current source. I'm used to working with voltage sources and maybe I'm choking on nothing but I would like some guidance on how to solve this.

[image: 2nd order Circuit]

Since we have a DC current source and an AC one, I thought that maybe I could use the superposition theorem and calculate \$V(t)\$ step by step by turning off and on the sources one by one.
If we switch off the AC source the part with the inductor practically has no meaning (correct me if I'm wrong but as I said I'm a beginner) and we can simply calculate \$V(t)\$. The problem is when I turn off the DC source and turn on the AC source. Since I'm used to having voltage sources and not current sources I became a bit unsure on how this goes.

I searched a bit on the net and I found that it is possible to use Milman's theorem with AC sources but it was mentioned that that was possible only when you have 2 or more sources.

As I'm writing this I also thought of something else. We have an AC current and when we have AC sources we consider the impedance (I simply think of them as resistors in a way), and since we have a current source the "resistance" of the inductor doesn't change that; can we simply use the current divider to find the current through the capacitor? And once we find that we can simply use $$I=C \times \frac{dv}{dt}$$ and from here we find \$v\$? Is this a proper way of thinking?

I'm asking for some clues on how to solve this, if possible. I don't need calculations, I just need to understand the thought process.

Comment: Can you show where exactly you got stuck? If you do so, someone might be able to point the finger exactly where in your equations you went wrong.

Comment: Tell us exactly what the exercise says, not your interpretation of it.

Comment: @Chu the exercise says find the voltage across the capacitor.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen thing is I'm unsure on how to start. What I said above is how I would solve the problem and asked if this way of thinking is acceptable to solve this particular problem.

Comment: Use Laplace ...

Comment: `Since we have a DC current source ` - it looks like a voltage source to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *So basically what I'm asking is some clues on how to solve this if
> possible. I don't need calculations I just need to understand the
> thought process.*

Here's how I would simplify things: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Another thing if possible. I was thinking of doing the superposition theorem where i first consider the circuit with the dc source then we turn that off and consider it with the ac source. When we are at the ac source part since inductor in series with ac current it doesnt affect it and i was thinking of doing a current divider and then finding the v(t) using the integral. Is this a viable option?

Comment: Yes, that's a viable option but I doubt it's as simple as trying to reduce the circuit to its minimal complexity (as per my answer).